# Getting WebGrease exception while starting application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was getting System.Web.Razor version conflict exceptions after I installed DotNetOpenAuth. So, I reverted the packages and uninstalled DotNetOpenAuth for now. But now I am getting below exception since long time -

*Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition  does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

Why is this happening? And how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried re installing the **Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization** through Package Manager Console? That should resolve the dependencies.